# Generic List with Exception not working as Intended

Tags: java, generics

The `m1()` call doesn't throw any run-time exception instead it executes properly.

However, as per my  understanding it should through exception as  - **RuntimeException class can not extends itself.**

```
 class Test1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<RuntimeException> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(new IllegalArgumentException());
        l.add(new RuntimeException());
        m1(l);
    }

public static void m1(List<? extends RuntimeException> l) {
        for (RuntimeException a : l)
            System.out.println(a);
    }

}
```

Can some one help me understand this behavior.

Comment: You've misunderstood `extends` in this context.  When it comes to a bound on a type parameter, `extends` actually means "extends, implements, or is equal to".  So in this case, `RuntimeException` is indeed a type that `extends RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 0):

**? extends T is called upper bounded**

```
The upper bounded wildcard, <? extends Foo>, where Foo is any type, matches Foo and any subtype of Foo. The process method can access the list elements as type Foo:

public static void process(List<? extends Foo> list) {
    for (Foo elem : list) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Hope this make sense as  T is any type that matches T and any subtype of T

Answer (score 0):

Your function could be rewritten as follows:

```
public <T extends RuntimeException> static void m1(List<T> l) {
    for (T a : l)
        System.out.println(a);
    }

}
```

It's clearer now that the type `T` is unknown but it inherits the traits of a `RuntimeException`.

But you have a wildcard bounded type here: `? extends RuntimeException`. So how can you iterate and retrieve objects?

All you know is that whatever it's inside, it's shares the traits of a `RuntimeException`, so that's why you use

```
for (RuntimeException a : l) { ... }
```

You can't do `for (Exception a : l)` over a `List<RuntimeException>` as this would open doors to (e.g) `IOException`s, which aren't `RuntimeException`'s.

But you could have `public static void m1(List<? extends Exception> l);` and pass it your `List<RuntimeException>`; but you'd need to iterate over it with `for (Exception a : l)`.

---

You could also look at it with the help of `instanceof`.

Is `RuntimeException instanceof RuntimeException`? Yes, although it isn't a subclass.